# PHP - Merge and Combine Array

Tags: php, array-merge

I have 3 arrays as follows:

Array 1:

```
array 1: [
  0 => array[
    "product_id" => "a"
    "quantity_1" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array[
    "product_id" => "b"
    "quantity_1" => "2"
  ]
  2 => array[
    "product_id" => "c"
    "quantity_1" => "1"
  ]
]
```

Array 2:

```
array 2: [
  0 => array[
    "product_id" => "a"
    "quantity_2" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array[
    "product_id" => "d"
    "quantity_2" => "2"
  ]
]
```

My desired result is:

```
array 3: [
  0 => array[
    "product_id" => "a"
    "quantity_1" => "1"
    "quantity_2" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array[
    "product_id" => "b"
    "quantity_1" => "2"
  ]
  2 => array[
    "product_id" => "c"
    "quantity_1" => "1"
  ]
  3 => array[
    "product_id" => "d"
    "quantity_2" => "2"
  ]
]
```

I tried using the array_combine() function but the result was not as expected

Any help much appreciated! Thanks very much!

Comment: There is no "core" function to combine these (in their current format)... I am assuming you want the product Id's to match up when combined...  That said it's quite trivial to do with a loop.  If you make the product ID the key then you can combine them using something like `array_merge_recursive`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your willing to make the product_id the key, then you can do it like this:

```
$a = [
  0 => [
    "product_id" => "a",
    "quantity_1" => "1"
  ],
  1 => [
    "product_id" => "b",
    "quantity_1" => "2"
  ],
  2 => [
    "product_id" => "c",
    "quantity_1" => "1"
  ]
];

$b =  [
  0 => [
    "product_id" => "a",
    "quantity_2" => "1"
  ],
  1 => [
    "product_id" => "d",
    "quantity_2" => "2"
  ]
];

 print_r(
      array_replace_recursive(
             array_column($a, null, 'product_id'),
             array_column($b, null, 'product_id')
      )
 );
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => a
            [quantity_1] => 1
            [quantity_2] => 1
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => b
            [quantity_1] => 2
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => c
            [quantity_1] => 1
        )

    [d] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => d
            [quantity_2] => 2
        )

)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5996815849e2c18b4fe360b22c5db986d6ce96f3)

You can always remove the key from the results with `array_values` like this:

```
 print_r(
    array_values(
      array_replace_recursive(
             array_column($a, null, 'product_id'),
             array_column($b, null, 'product_id')
      )
    )
 );
```

-Note- the product_ids MUST be unique in each array, for this to work.   Otherwise you can do it simply with a foreach loop.

```
$c = [];

foreach(array_merge($a,$b) as $v){
    $k = $v['product_id'];
    if(!isset($c[$k])){
        $c[$k] = $v;
    }else{
        $c[$k] = array_merge($c[$k],$v);
    }
}

print_r($c);
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3427e5228ca4952c2ad5e0cdaf4aefc89e86736a)

I would post the output, but it's the same :) - which is the point.  Also I prefer to reference the keys a little as possible.  It can make maintaining the code a bit easier.